# how to read multiple elements in xml in sequence with python

Tags: python, xml

I have a xml files in this format:

```
<stage rend="italic center" type="entrance"> aaaaa </stage>
<sp who="#F-mm-duk">bbbbb </sp>
<sp who="#smdwo">ccccc </sp>
<sp who="#F-mm-acb">cccc </sp>
<stage rend="italic center" type="entrance"> ddddd </stage>
```

how could I extract the text from those elements in order to be :
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
ddddd

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care some exceptional situations, like the text includes `'>', '</'` etc.

You can use one regex expression to extract out the texts of all nodes.

**the codes is like below:**

```
import re

xml_str = """
<stage rend="italic center" type="entrance"> aaaaa </stage>
<sp who="#F-mm-duk">bbbbb </sp>
<sp who="#smdwo">ccccc </sp>
<sp who="#F-mm-acb">cccc </sp>
<stage rend="italic center" type="entrance"> ddddd </stage>
"""

match_list = re.findall(r'>(?P<xml>.*)</', xml_str, flags=0)
print (match_list)
```

**output:**

```
[' aaaaa ', 'bbbbb ', 'ccccc ', 'cccc ', ' ddddd ']
[Finished in 0.287s]
```

But the better solution is using one XML library like [xml.etree.elementtree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html), then pick out all texts for the nodes.

**The codes will be like below:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_str = """
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
<stage rend="italic center" type="entrance"> aaaaa </stage>
<sp who="#F-mm-duk">bbbbb </sp>
<sp who="#smdwo">ccccc </sp>
<sp who="#F-mm-acb">cccc </sp>
<stage rend="italic center" type="entrance"> ddddd </stage>
</data>
"""

tree = ET.fromstring(xml_str.strip())
for child in tree:
    print(child.text)
```

And some XML libraries support XPath(`xml.etree.elementtree` provides limited support.). You can google it then study how to implement same output with XPath.